# Компиляция pngnq

Tags: c++

Добрый вечер!
Помогите, пожалуйста, скомпилировать проект [pngnq](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pngnq/files/). У меня при компиляции через MinGW выдает:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mingw.org/wiki/FAQ и смотрите ответ на вопрос "How do I get pkg-config installed?"

Comment: Спасибо! вроде как разобрался, не подскажите еще как установить libpng.
mingw-get install mingw32-libpng не работает